# ggplot ignores the size argument in the aes() function in geom_point() function in scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, scatter-plot

In plotting a Scatter plot with ggplot the size argument in the `aes()` function in `geom_point()` function is ignored.

Below please find more information.

My dataframe is the following:

```
> actbins
           Var1 Freq prprob ObsFreq    Obsprob
1      (0,0.01]  997  0.005      17 0.01705115
2   (0.01,0.02] 1126  0.015      22 0.01953819
3   (0.02,0.03]  896  0.025      16 0.01785714
4   (0.03,0.04]  742  0.035      32 0.04312668
5   (0.04,0.05]  603  0.045      19 0.03150912
6   (0.05,0.06]  479  0.055      30 0.06263048
7   (0.06,0.07]  373  0.065      19 0.05093834
8   (0.07,0.08]  341  0.075      20 0.05865103
9   (0.08,0.09]  317  0.085      21 0.06624606
10   (0.09,0.1]  258  0.095      16 0.06201550
11   (0.1,0.11]  237  0.105      18 0.07594937
12  (0.11,0.12]  177  0.115      22 0.12429379
13  (0.12,0.13]  182  0.125      20 0.10989011
14  (0.13,0.14]  132  0.135      19 0.14393939
15  (0.14,0.15]  137  0.145      18 0.13138686
16  (0.15,0.16]  141  0.155      23 0.16312057
17  (0.16,0.17]  132  0.165      25 0.18939394
18  (0.17,0.18]  118  0.175      22 0.18644068
19  (0.18,0.19]   89  0.185      20 0.22471910
20   (0.19,0.2]   97  0.195      17 0.17525773
21   (0.2,0.21]   98  0.205      20 0.20408163
22  (0.21,0.22]  109  0.215      18 0.16513761
23  (0.22,0.23]   94  0.225      14 0.14893617
24  (0.23,0.24]   82  0.235      22 0.26829268
25  (0.24,0.25]   89  0.245      29 0.32584270
26  (0.25,0.26]   74  0.255      16 0.21621622
27  (0.26,0.27]   55  0.265      16 0.29090909
28  (0.27,0.28]   76  0.275      15 0.19736842
29  (0.28,0.29]   69  0.285      23 0.33333333
30   (0.29,0.3]   73  0.295      25 0.34246575
31   (0.3,0.31]   50  0.305      12 0.24000000
32  (0.31,0.32]   66  0.315      22 0.33333333
33  (0.32,0.33]   45  0.325      17 0.37777778
34  (0.33,0.34]   49  0.335      13 0.26530612
35  (0.34,0.35]   43  0.345      18 0.41860465
36  (0.35,0.36]   55  0.355      27 0.49090909
37  (0.36,0.37]   44  0.365      15 0.34090909
38  (0.37,0.38]   43  0.375      20 0.46511628
39  (0.38,0.39]   49  0.385      21 0.42857143
40   (0.39,0.4]   47  0.395      19 0.40425532
41   (0.4,0.41]   34  0.405      16 0.47058824
42  (0.41,0.42]   41  0.415      25 0.60975610
43  (0.42,0.43]   34  0.425      19 0.55882353
44  (0.43,0.44]   21  0.435      11 0.52380952
45  (0.44,0.45]   29  0.445      13 0.44827586
46  (0.45,0.46]   23  0.455       7 0.30434783
47  (0.46,0.47]   13  0.465       6 0.46153846
48  (0.47,0.48]   21  0.475      11 0.52380952
49  (0.48,0.49]   19  0.485       8 0.42105263
50   (0.49,0.5]   16  0.495       7 0.43750000
51   (0.5,0.51]   17  0.505      13 0.76470588
52  (0.51,0.52]   18  0.515       9 0.50000000
53  (0.52,0.53]    4  0.525       1 0.25000000
54  (0.53,0.54]   15  0.535       5 0.33333333
55  (0.54,0.55]    5  0.545       1 0.20000000
56  (0.55,0.56]    8  0.555       5 0.62500000
57  (0.56,0.57]    2  0.565       2 1.00000000
58  (0.57,0.58]    9  0.575       6 0.66666667
59  (0.58,0.59]    6  0.585       3 0.50000000
60   (0.59,0.6]   10  0.595       3 0.30000000
61   (0.6,0.61]    5  0.605       3 0.60000000
62  (0.61,0.62]   14  0.615       8 0.57142857
63  (0.62,0.63]    2  0.625       1 0.50000000
64  (0.63,0.64]    0  0.635       0        NaN
65  (0.64,0.65]    4  0.645       2 0.50000000
66  (0.65,0.66]    2  0.655       0 0.00000000
67  (0.66,0.67]    3  0.665       2 0.66666667
68  (0.67,0.68]    0  0.675       0        NaN
69  (0.68,0.69]    0  0.685       0        NaN
70   (0.69,0.7]    0  0.695       0        NaN
71   (0.7,0.71]    0  0.705       0        NaN
72  (0.71,0.72]    1  0.715       0 0.00000000
73  (0.72,0.73]    0  0.725       0        NaN
74  (0.73,0.74]    0  0.735       0        NaN
75  (0.74,0.75]    0  0.745       0        NaN
76  (0.75,0.76]    0  0.755       0        NaN
77  (0.76,0.77]    0  0.765       0        NaN
78  (0.77,0.78]    0  0.775       0        NaN
79  (0.78,0.79]    1  0.785       0 0.00000000
80   (0.79,0.8]    0  0.795       0        NaN
81   (0.8,0.81]    0  0.805       0        NaN
82  (0.81,0.82]    0  0.815       0        NaN
83  (0.82,0.83]    0  0.825       0        NaN
84  (0.83,0.84]    0  0.835       0        NaN
85  (0.84,0.85]    0  0.845       0        NaN
86  (0.85,0.86]    0  0.855       0        NaN
87  (0.86,0.87]    0  0.865       0        NaN
88  (0.87,0.88]    0  0.875       0        NaN
89  (0.88,0.89]    0  0.885       0        NaN
90   (0.89,0.9]    0  0.895       0        NaN
91   (0.9,0.91]    0  0.905       0        NaN
92  (0.91,0.92]    0  0.915       0        NaN
93  (0.92,0.93]    0  0.925       0        NaN
94  (0.93,0.94]    0  0.935       0        NaN
95  (0.94,0.95]    0  0.945       0        NaN
96  (0.95,0.96]    0  0.955       0        NaN
97  (0.96,0.97]    0  0.965       0        NaN
98  (0.97,0.98]    0  0.975       0        NaN
99  (0.98,0.99]    0  0.985       0        NaN
100    (0.99,1]    0  0.995       0        NaN
```

My code is the following:

```
  ggplot(actbins, aes(x = prprob, y = Obsprob)) +
    geom_point(aes(size = Freq), color = 'red', size = 2, alpha = 0.5)
```

The output is the following:

**Scatter plot:**

[image]

For some reason the size argument in the `aes()` function is ignored.

Could you please explain why this is the case and advise accordingly?

Comment: You are overriding with `size = 2` outside the `aes()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forced the size with `size = 2`. Remove that and you will get a graph like this.

`ggplot(actbins, aes(x = prprob, y = Obsprob)) +
    geom_point(aes(size = Freq), color = 'red', alpha = 0.5, show.legend = T)`
[image]